# Check relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array with the ID of the services, and there is an array with the Product.
They are related to each other as Many To Many.
For expamle:
Product

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Service

```
[2, 3, 6]
```

Table

| product_id | service_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 8 |

How can I check whether a product belongs to a service?

Comment: So do you need to check which pairs exist of all possible pairs? In this case all possible pairs would be (1,2), (1, 3), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 6) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged it as Laravel, and mentioned "Many to Many", which case, presumably, there are Eloquent relationships in place.

That being the case, then if a Service has one or more Products, you can check if a specific Service has a specific Product using :

```
$service = Service::find(2);
$product = Product::find(8);
if($service->products->contains($product)) { 
    echo "Service has that product";
} else { 
    echo "Service does not have that product";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Eloquent, you can use query builder

```
$exists = DB::table('service_product')
    ->whereServiceId($service_id)
    ->whereProductId($product_id)
    ->count() > 0;
```